# Trouble Sending Emails with Prepared Templates in Laravel:

Tags: php, laravel, email

I'm encountering errors and issues, especially when handling exceptions and escaping HTML characters. I'd appreciate any guidance on best practices for sending emails with templates using laravel 10  and any insights into resolving the problems I'm facing. Thank you in advance!

In mail only html code is visible expected is html page .

I am using [`https://app.bootstrapemail.com/templates/free-simple-card`][1]

```
 public function prepareTemplate($subject, $body, $templateId)
    {
        $subject = htmlentities($subject, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $body = htmlentities($body, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        // Load the template from your database or source
        $template = $this->templates::where('InternalID', $templateId)->first(); // Assuming you want to retrieve a single template.

        $templateHeader = $template->Header;
        $templateFooter = $template->Footer;

    // Replace placeholders in the template body with dynamic content
        $templateBody = str_replace('{{ subject }}', $subject, $template->Body);
        $templateBody = str_replace('{{ body }}', $body, $templateBody);

        // Escape HTML characters in subject and body


        // Combine the header, dynamic body, and footer
        $completeTemplate = $templateHeader . $templateBody . $templateFooter;

        return $completeTemplate;

    } 

 // SendMail

  



 public function SendMail($notification)
    {
    
        // Inject the Templates model when creating TemplateService
        $templateService = new TemplateService(new Templates);
        $template  =  $templateService->prepareTemplate($notification->Subject,$notification->Body,1);
    
        try {
            Mail::to($notification->Contact)->send(new MyTestEmail($notification,$template));
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->updateNotificationService->UpdateTriedCount($notification);
            Log::info(['Failed Notification '=>$notification]);
           return false;
        }
    }
```

I am using this template  https://app.bootstrapemail.com/templates/free-simple-card

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBZAi.png

    <?php
    
    namespace App\Mail;
    
    use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
    use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
    use Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Content;
    use Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Envelope;
    use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
    
    
    class MyTestEmail extends Mailable
    {
        use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    
        /**
         * Create a new message instance.
         */
    
        private $notification;
        private $template;
    
        public function __construct($notification ,$template)
        {
            $this->notification = $notification;
            $this->template = $template;
        }
    
        /**
         * Get the message envelope.
         */
        public function envelope(): Envelope
        {
            return new Envelope(
                subject: $this->notification->Subject,
            );
        }
    
        /**
         * Get the message content definition.
         */
        public function content(): Content
        {
            return new Content(
                html: 'mail.test-email',
                with: [
                    'template'=>$this->template
                ]
            );
        }
    
        /**
         * Get the attachments for the message.
         *
         * @return array<int, \Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Attachment>
         */
        public function attachments(): array
        {
            return [];
        }
    }
```

Comment: *"I'm encountering errors and issues"* You should be more specific about them.

Comment: I am trying to send mail with html template provide by bootstrap.mail template. i am using laravel 10 , the problem here is html code directly send in mail

Comment: So you mean that HTML is not interpreted? OK, but you didn't post your `MyTestEmail` class, so we have no idea what it does.

Comment: sorry for the late response , I have added MyTestEmail file .

Comment: can you add your `mail.test-email` file ?

Comment: I have only this line {{ $template }} in mail.test-email file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail
   2.in test.email.blade page updated as {!! $template !!}

After this 2 steps issue is fixed and working as expected .